# Can I resolve props before setting a ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```js
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { Box } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useBoundingRect } from "../hooks";

export default function Item({ children, setItemPosition, itemWidth, gap }) {
  const [ref, { x }] = useBoundingRect();

  useLayoutEffect(() => setItemPosition(Math.round(x)), [x]);

  return (
    <Box
      ref={ref}
      w={`${itemWidth}px`}
      _notLast={{
        mr: `${gap}px`
      }}
      flex="0 0 auto"
    >
      {children}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

The above component is mapped by a parent component. It sits horizontally in a carousel I am building.

`ref` is assigned to the dom element and a hook (see below for hook) attaches a resize event listener to use `.getBoundingClientRect()` to `return` the elements `x` position value.

The `x` value is then passed to the parent state in `setItemPosition()` which has been passed down in props.

Secondary to this, `itemWidth` is passed down in props and assigned to the DOM element, giving it its width. This happens **AFTER** the `x` value has already been calculated which means that the `x` positions are out of date and have recorded a value minus the width of the previous element in the carousel.

How can I record the `x` value **AFTER** the DOM element has been assigned its width?

## I have tried:

• Tried using `useLayoutEffect` to assign the width and then `useEffect` to pass the `x` position but it didn't work.

• Reversing how the `itemWidth` is calculated and instead of calculating it in the parent and passing it down, passing down from the parent only the value it uses to calculates from and doing the calculation in the child and passing it up.

### The hook

```js
import { useState, useCallback, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { debounce } from "../utils";

function getDimensionObject(node) {
  const rect = node.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    width: rect.width,
    height: rect.height,
    top: rect.top,
    left: rect.left,
    x: rect.x,
    y: rect.y,
    right: rect.right,
    bottom: rect.bottom
  };
}

export default function useBoundingRect(limit) {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({});
  const [node, setNode] = useState(null);

  const ref = useCallback((node) => setNode(node), []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if ("undefined" !== typeof window && node) {
      const measure = () =>
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() =>
          setDimensions(getDimensionObject(node))
        );

      measure();

      const listener = debounce(limit ? limit : 250, measure);

      window.addEventListener("resize", listener);
      window.addEventListener("scroll", listener);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", listener);
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", listener);
      };
    }
  }, [node, limit]);

  return [ref, dimensions, node];
}
```

Comment: Can't you pass `setItemPosition` as an argument to `useBoundingRect` and then call it when you call setDimensions?

Comment: I thought I knew what you were getting at but when attempting it I just end up causing infinite render loops. If you get a moment could you elaborate?